# $e_{i}Ae_{j} \neq 0$ implies that $e_{i}rad(A)e_{j} \neq 0$.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field with $rad^2(A)=0$. Let $\{e_{1},\dots,e_{n}\}$ be a complete set of primitive orthogonal idempotents. Suppose that $e_{i}Ae_{j} \neq 0$ for $i \neq j$. Why does this implies that $e_{i}rad(A)e_{j} \neq 0$?

Would this follow from Malcev's theorem? or why exactly?

Comment: Follows from Schur lemma; also radical-square zero is not necessary.

Comment: By Wedderburn theorem $B=A/rad(A)$ is just direct sum of matrix algebras, since $e_i$'s are orthogonal, we can assume $B$ is direct sum of the underlying field, where $e_i$ is the projection onto the $i$-th copy.  If $e_i rad(A) e_j = 0$, then we have $e_i B e_j\neq 0$, but $e_i Be_j = Hom_B(Be_i,Be_j)$, then Schur lemma tells you this is zero, a contradiction.

Comment: Nakayama lemma would be an overkill.  You started with $Hom_A(Ae_i,Ae_j) = e_i Ae_j \neq 0$, and assume the subspace $Hom_A(Ae_i, rad(Ae_j)) = Hom_A(Ae_i, rad(A) e_j) = e_i rad(A) e_j  = 0$, then clearly the quotient (vector space) $Hom_A(Ae_i, (A/rad(A))e_j) = e_i (A/rad(A)) e_j \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Wedderburn theorem $B:=A/\mathrm{rad}(A)$ is just direct sum of matrix algebras.  Since $e_i$'s are orthogonal to each other, we can assume $B$ is direct sum of the underlying field, where $e_i$ is the projection onto the $i$-th copy.  Schur Lemma says that $e_i B e_j \cong \mathrm{Hom}_B(Be_i,Be_j)=0$.

If we have $\mathrm{Hom}_A(Ae_i,Ae_j)\cong e_iAe_j \neq 0$, but the subspace $\mathrm{Hom}_A(Ae_i,\mathrm{rad}(A)e_j)\cong e_i\mathrm{rad}(A)e_j=0$, then we have $e_iBe_j\neq 0$, a contradiction.